# PL SQL Query for grouping Department names

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to PL/SQL and I am stuck at this one point where I am unable to group data by department names. my query is as follows

```
DECLARE
      CURSOR dept_cur IS

      select department_name ,  NVL(employee_name , 'N/A') , NVL(employee.JOB , 'N/A') ,                    NVL(to_char(hire_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'N/A')
      FROM department FULL OUTER JOIN employee ON department.department_id = employee.department_id 
      order by department_name , employee_name;

      v_department_name department.department_name%TYPE;
      v_employee_name  employee.employee_name%type;
      v_employee_job  employee.job%type;
      v_hire_date  VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
        OPEN dept_cur;
        fetch dept_cur into v_department_name , v_employee_name , v_employee_job , v_hire_date ;

        IF dept_cur%FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEPARTMENT_NAME     EMPLOYEE NAME , EMPLOYEE JOB , HIRE DATE');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------');

         WHILE dept_cur%FOUND LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lpad(v_department_name, 11) || lpad(v_employee_name, 16) || lpad(v_employee_job, 22)|| lpad(v_hire_date,15));
                fetch dept_cur into v_department_name , v_employee_name , v_employee_job , v_hire_date ;
      END LOOP;

      ELSE
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No output.');
      END IF;



      CLOSE dept_cur;

END;
```

I want the output to be something like this , but my query returns the entire list .

The number of employees in ACCOUNTING is 2

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME           JOB                          HIRE DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------
JONES                   PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT            02-APR-81
STEEL                   PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT            02-MAR-83
```

and the same for other departments as well. I understand its a minor change in the PL SQL block logic  , but I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR dept_cur IS
        SELECT department_name,
            COUNT(employee.employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY department_name),
            NVL(employee_name, 'N/A'),
            NVL(employee.JOB, 'N/A'),
            NVL(to_char(hire_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'N/A')
        FROM department
        FULL OUTER JOIN employee ON department.department_id = employee.department_id 
        ORDER BY department_name, employee_name;

    v_department_name    department.department_name%TYPE;
    last_department_name department.department_name%TYPE;
    v_department_count   NUMBER;
    v_employee_name      employee.employee_name%TYPE;
    v_employee_job       employee.job%TYPE;
    v_hire_date          VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
    OPEN dept_cur;
    FETCH dept_cur INTO v_department_name, v_department_count, v_employee_name, v_employee_job, v_hire_date;
    last_department_name := NULL;

    IF dept_cur%FOUND THEN
        WHILE dept_cur%FOUND LOOP
            IF last_department_name IS NULL OR last_department_name <> v_department_name THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of employees in ' || v_department_name || ' is ' || to_char(v_department_count));
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE NAME           EMPLOYEE JOB                 HIRE DATE');
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------------------------');
                last_department_name := v_department_name;
            END IF;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(v_employee_name, 24) || rpad(v_employee_job, 24)|| lpad(v_hire_date,14));

            FETCH dept_cur INTO v_department_name, v_department_count, v_employee_name, v_employee_job, v_hire_date;
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No output.');
    END IF;

    CLOSE dept_cur;
END;
```

It uses an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) `COUNT() OVER ()` to count the number of employees in the result for each department, and inserts that on every row for that department.

Since the query is already ordered by department, it just checks for when that changes to another value, and then prints the headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot but your query returns Accouting has 2 employees..Record 1 and then Accounting has 2 employees... Records 2. How do I have "Accounting has 2 Employees" only once , followed by the 2 records. Also I havent yet played around with Partitioning Tables so is there a simpler way to do this??

Comment: Ah. I forgot to update the `last_department_name` variable. Fixed now.

Comment: `PARTITION BY` is the simplest way I can think of. Any other way would involve a lot more code; Either SQL or loops and temporary tables.

Comment: Put shortly: Analytic functions are applied after the final row-set has been determined, so you cannot filter or sort by their values. Partitioning is similar to a `GROUP BY`, with the result is copied to every row in the group.